# Creating variables from factor records in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I am kind of lost, I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
tract   ageClass    count
    1      [0-4]       71
    2      [0-4]      192
    3      [0-4]       81
    1      [5-8]        9
    2      [5-8]       86
    3      [5-8]       42
```

I would like to have this result:

```
tract   [0-4]   [5-8]
    1      71       9
    2     192      86
    3      81      42
```

I have been looking in the internet for a solution for quite some time but so far nothing... any idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: try `xtabs` to perform cross tabulation

Comment: the function reshape works to (even if it is a bit hard), `reshape(data=df, idvar = "tract", v.names="count", timevar ="ageClass", direction = "wide")`

Comment: @MamounBenghezal `reshape` is from base R, you don't need any package for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ageClass <- c("[0-4]", "[5-8]")
ageClassDF <- lapply(ageClass, function(x) dx[which(dx$ageClass==x), ])

ageClassDF <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "tract.1", all = TRUE), ageClassDF )
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question? Any explanation for the code?

Comment: Indeed. I found a solution: I am subsetting the data.frame (dx) with lapply. Then I recreate it through the Reduce function. Smooth...

Answer (score 7):

Three possible options I can think of (assuming your data set called `df`)

```
xtabs(count ~ tract + ageClass, df) 
#       ageClass
# tract [0-4] [5-8]
#     1    71     9
#     2   192    86
#     3    81    42
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, tract ~ ageClass, value.var = "count") 
#   tract [0-4] [5-8]
# 1     1    71     9
# 2     2   192    86
# 3     3    81    42
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, ageClass, count)
#   tract [0-4] [5-8]
# 1     1    71     9
# 2     2   192    86
# 3     3    81    42
```